# Getting Gmail Messages

Tags: javascript, gmail, google-apps-script

I have a code that takes the body of emails in Gmail

But the body comes with "HTML tags", how I filter out these "Tags" ?

Example:

The body:

```
<span><span style="font-weight:bold" dir="ltr">eu</span>: 
<a href="http://neuhaus.com.br" target="_blank">neuhaus.com.br</a>
D6477233ACC7C56D</span><br>
```

The body filtrated I need:

eu: neuhaus.com.br  D6477233ACC7C56D

code:

```
function processPending() {  
  var label_pending = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Teste');  
  var label_done = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('TesteDone');  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var rowstart = (sheet.getLastRow() + 1)

  var threads = label_pending.getThreads();  

  for (var t in threads) {  
    var thread = threads[t];  

    var message = thread.getMessages()[0];

    var messbody = message.getBody();

    thread.removeLabel(label_pending);  
    thread.addLabel(label_done);

    sheet.getRange(rowstart, getColIndexByName('Conteúdo')).setValue(messbody);
    rowstart++;
  }
  return 0;
}  

function getColIndexByName(colName) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var row = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues();
  for (i in row[0]) {
    var name = row[0][i];
    if (name == colName) {
      return parseInt(i) + 1;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent) property of the DOM element. It has its HTML tags stripped off.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using regular expression to strip the tags

```
var stripped = messbody.replace(/(\<[^>]+\>)+/g,' ');
```

There are sometimes issues with this, so you should be careful, but for simple HTML like the sample you've listed, this will work.

Comment: A regex is probably not the best option. I guess it comes down to whether the angle brackets are in the text as literals or as &gt; and &lt;

Answer (score 0):

If allowed to use jQuery, you should check the [$.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function.

```
var text = $('<div>Text 1<b>Bold Text</b> Text 2</div>').text();
// stores 'Text 1 Bold Text Text 2'
```